# check current running process in a terminal through another terminal

Tags: linux, ps

Lets say i write a program where parent calls a child and im running both of them in an infinite loop like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main()
{

    if(fork()){
            printf("hola\n");
            printf("parent's id is : %d\n", getpid());
            while(1);
    }
    else{
            printf("hello\n");
            printf("child's id is : %d\n", getpid());
            while(1);
    }
}
```

Now, i want to see current running processes in the first terminal from another terminal, how do I do that, I've tried some variations of ps but none of them seem to be useful here.

edit: In another terminal `ps -el` or `ps afx` does the job but I dont want to list of all background processes running, I only want current foreground process from that terminal, I can swear I knew a command like that, just cant remember it now.

Comment: Well, `ps ax` should show you a process list with two instances of the program above after you started it. Or what exactly are you trying to see?

Comment: @Ctx , ideally, I should get pid and ppid of both processes and ofc bash and ps processes

Comment: If you "tried some variations of ps" you should show in your question what you have tried. In case you made a mistake, someone might help you to fix the command. It may also help to understand what output you want to get. Please add all clarification or requested information **to the question**.

Comment: @JerseyDevil sounds like `ps afx` could be what you need; it also includes the process hierarchy

Comment: @Bodo , edited some stuff, much appreciated

Comment: @JerseyDevil If you know the terminal name, you can try `ps ft tty4` (or similar)

Comment: Did you try `pgrep`?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for `ps -e|grep pts/1` for terminal one and likewise.
This shows current running foreground processes in the terminal defined.